# Strategies to compare between 2 virtual machines

Tags: linux, vmware-esxi, redhat, virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere

I am writing a set of codes with Ansible/Terraform to deploy the same VM which I am already deploying using Bash scripts that interact with VMWare (vSphere 5.5) API.

I have searched around how I could compare the final result: the VMs itself, but unfortunately I couldn't find any suggestion of tool. The idea is to deploy 1 VM with the Bash script and 1 with the Terraform/Ansible code and compare if the final results are the same: packages, version of packages, mounting points, VM size (RAM, Disk, CPU), network (not IP's of course, but route, DNS entries, etc).

Is there any tool for that or I should write some bash/python script for that?

Comment: Isn't there a Terraform module that will directly interact with ESXi/vCenter and config that the build plan was complete?

Comment: For sure there is such module, but I need to compare the 2 vms created. I need to be sure that the final result is the same with Ansible/terraform and my old scripts.

Comment: You'll need a configuration management system such as Puppet that can compare the list of VM properties you will have to define.